Is image projection a good test quality for hyperopia glasses?
I've just bought a new pair of glasses for hyperopia, and want to test the lens quality. If I use the lenses just like a magnifying glass, to project the image of a lamp onto a wall, the image should be on focus, when the lens is in the proper distance? If I always get a blurred image of the lamp, no matter the lens distance, should I conclude that the lens is of bad quality for the correction of hyperopia? Or aren't the two things necessarily correlated?
PS: The glasses improves my reading vision, but is giving me some headache. I don't know if that's because it's the first time I'm using it, or if that's because the lenses are bad.

Don't ask random strangers on the Internet for health advice. Please see a qualified optometrist (or whatever they're called in your country).

The point of glasses is to correct how light rays fall inside the eye. I would assume the best test would be to wear them.

@PM2Ring Indeed. But still I got curious about the physics of it.

@Triatticus Please read the PS.

We physicists invented optics, so there's really no clear reason to leave everything to optometrists, who merely know how to apply it. @PM 2Ring

My optometrist advised that there is an adjustment period if you've never worn glasses before. I just got glasses and did have slight nausea when first wearing hem for more than a few minutes. But everyone would have their own experience and that really isn't a physics question itself. But a lens won't fix a projection if it isn't directly between the source and your eye. Projecting it to a wall still then leads to those light rays bouncing off the wall into your uncorrected eye.

Yes, a lens for hyperopia (long-sightedness) should give a sharp image of a lamp when projected onto a plane perpendicular to the lens axis. But your lenses should be the appropriate strength (focal length) for what your eyes need. Generally, that means they let you focus comfortably on print at your preferred reading distance. Give your eyes time to get used to your new glasses. Don't read with them for long periods for the first few days.

@Triatticus It seems you missed the point. I can see the lamp image on the wall very well, when the projection is made with a magnifying glass, and I don't need to wear my new glasses for that. So I know that the projection made with the glasses is not as sharp. So I think that maybe the lenses are bad (or maybe because of their shape, not a perfect circle like the magnifying glass). Anyway, thanks for the advice about the adjustment period.

@PM2Ring Yes, I can focus on print at my preferred reading distance, though it's not comfortable at all. So yes, I'm reading for only a short time right now. Let's see if it improves with time. Thank you!

For the physics of Hyperopia, see https://thelostcontacts.com/the-optics-of-vision-lesson-7-hyperopia/
